# Restrict uiscrollview scroll area

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

I have an image with multiple portions. I'll try to explain with following diagram:

```
--|----------|---------|---
  |   1      |   2     |
  |          |         |
--|----------|---------|---
  |   3      |   4     |
  |          |         |
--|----------|---------|---
```

In the above diagram 1,2,3 and 4 are the sections of the big image. I am using an UIImageView within an UIScrollView. I am showing one part at a time to the user. So that it appears like the sections are individual images. If I am showing section 3, I am hiding all the parts of the image but section 3 and change the image coordinate such a way that section 3 appears middle of the screen. Till now, everything is working fine. Now I need to implement zoom on the sections. After zooming a section, user will be only allowed to scroll within the section and they won't be allowed to scroll outside the zoomed section. I am not able to implement the thing as if I set the contentoffset and contentsize property of the uiscrollview, it takes image out of the screen.

Can anybody suggest me how to implement this?

Below is the code I am using to position the scrollview.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float updatedCurrFrameX = originalFrame.origin.x*[scroll zoomScale];
    float updatedCurrFrameY = originalFrame.origin.y*[scroll zoomScale];
    float updatedCurrFrameWidth = originalFrame.size.width*[scroll zoomScale];
    float updatedCurrFrameHeight = originalFrame.size.height*[scroll zoomScale];

    CGRect visibleRect=CGRectMake(updatedCurrFrameX, updatedCurrFrameY, updatedCurrFrameWidth, updatedCurrFrameHeight);
    scroll.contentSize= visibleRect.size;
    scroll.contentOffset=visibleRect.origin;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` to be notified when the user zooms (`scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`) then act accordingly by setting `contentSize` and `contentOffset`. If you can't achieve the desired effect by adjusting the contentSize and offset, you might consider changing the scrollView's documentView when zoomed.